# How to tell my .NET application which IP address to request from?

Tags: .net

If I have a Windows server with more than one IP address, how do I pro grammatically tell different instances of my application to use a different IP address when communicating with the internet?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the context?

Comment: Are you using raw sockets? wcf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get round this problem by setting up port forwarding, so the server thought it was just using a different port, but from outside the router it looks like it's using a different IP address. I remember coming to the conclusion that a server can only be assigned one IP address, even if it receives from several.